# How can I submit an angular-ui modal with keyboard

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

angular-ui modals (see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ under *Modal*) can be default be cancelled by pressing escape. This option is configurable through the `keyboard` option to `$modal.open()`.

I would also like to be able to *submit* such a modal by using the keyboard, for example by pressing `Ctrl-Enter`. (I have several different dialogs of this kind in my app. Each modal has a different controller due to different input / output requirements.)

The button specification at the end of the angular template of the example in the documentation looks like this:

```
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

The rest of the example can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/uNeRrPI8CdZFNslcQzFy?p=preview

Here's a gist for adding an extra angular directive for keyboard shortcuts to elements with `ng-click` directives: https://gist.github.com/mkhatib/5802718 -- is this the best solution?

Comment: You can add a custom directive to the modal itself and listen to keydown events. Will look into that later when I have a real keyboard (I am on my smartphone)

Answer (score 4):

You could listen for a key event in the `ModalInstanceCtrl` like this:

```
function onKeydown(evt) {
  if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.which === 13) { // enter key
    evt.preventDefault();
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.ok();
    });
  }
}

$document.on('keydown', onKeydown);
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  $document.off('keydown', onKeydown);
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/CR0HxGzCVK2V2dAxzjX4?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. it looks like you reposted my example plnkr. Could you fix? 2. Without seeing your example, I wonder how it would work for multiple dialogs? (could be, depending on your $scope closure in the onKeyDown handler)

Comment: Fixed the plunker link. It works because all of your modals use the same controller `ModalInstanceCtrl` If you have multiple modal controllers, it may be better to extract the above logic out to a directive or service for reuse.

Comment: Nice working solution! However, I do use multiple controllers, because each modal requires different data input and output. :) -- do you mind if we wait a little longer in case any other interesting solutions are presented?

Comment: (I've added a sentence to my question explaining that there are different controllers for each modal)

Comment: Not at all. I will also try to think of an implementation that can be reused easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a directive working with Angular 1.3. It can be added as attribute of a form or anywhere inside a modal. Only one modal should be opened at at once.

```
/**
 * Submit form in modal on Enter key pressed.
 * Usage: <form org-submit-onenter="myModalCtrl.ok()"></form>
 *
 * Only one modal should be opened at at once.
 */
function orgSubmitOnenter($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 0,
    link: function($scope, element, attr) {
      if (!attr.orgSubmitOnenter) return;

      function onKeydown(event) {
        if (event.which === 13) { // Enter key
          event.preventDefault();
          $scope.$eval(attr.orgSubmitOnenter);
        }
      }
      $document.on('keydown', onKeydown);
      $scope.$on('modal.closing', function () {
        $document.off('keydown', onKeydown);
      });
    }
  }
}
angular
  .module('directives')
  .directive('orgSubmitOnenter', orgSubmitOnenter);
```